# Icon size pixely - Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

As you can see by the image below (this is my application) the icon images seem to be very pixelated and not smooth and clean like I would like them to be. I downloaded a larger image, roughly 256 x 256 and scaled it down to an 18 x 18 pixel image. Am I doing something wrong with these icons? I want something nice and smooth and nice to look at and not like somebody barfed an ugly icon all over the screen.

Can anybody help me out? Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the images you downloaded were png or jpeg images? Those file types are bitmaps and if you change their size there is often rendering issues like these. If you want the smoothest possible images you need to export the size you need from a vector image (for instance, in photoshop).

It may also have to do with a "retina display" device. On those devices your icons will need to be twice the size (or on an iPhone 6+, 3 times) you actually want them to display as.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure, check your images and maybe you can try to scale the images "on the fly".

Remember, it's a bad practice use bigger images, they'll take more memory for nothing.

```
func resizeImage(image: UIImage, newHeight: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    let scale = newHeight / image.size.height
    let newWidth = image.size.width * scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(newWidth, newHeight))
    image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight))
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
```